# Is it possible to programmatically read the `stdout` of another pty / tty without affecting its behavior?

Tags: linux, macos, pyserial, tmux, tty

I am attempting to programmatically read the output written by an application running in a specific tmux pane, so that I can determine when to send-keys to it from a controlling process.

In particular, I would like to automatically enter a password, but I do not want to enter it until I am sure the password prompt has appeared.

My current attempt has been to use `tty` to find the controlling `tty`, and then pass it to `pyserial` to try to read, since it appears to be able to read `tty`'s.  Note that in the real application, I have other ways of finding out the `tty`.

Unfortunately, as soon as I run the following code, the target tmux pane immediately closes.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttys013', timeout=1)
```

**Is it possible to read from a pty this way?**

I am running on OSX, but would appreciate a solution that works on both Linux and OSX.

Comment: Have you tried opening the tty as a file instead of a serial port? Most serial libraries will write to the device to set things like parity or baud rate even if you don't tell it to. This may be what's causing the tty to behave the way it does. Just open it like a file instead. I've done such things using `cat` or `tail` in bash without affecting the tty. If you can do it in bash you can do it in a program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, with python you would use `pexpect` to start the program and interact with it via a pty, but if you already have a program running in tmux you could simply use tmux's `pipe-pane` command to save a copy in a file of what is written to the screen. For example, for a pane number 1 you can give the shell command:

```sh
tmux pipe-pane -t 1 'cat >/tmp/capture'
```

and then tail the file `/tmp/capture`. (Use `tmux pipe-pane -t 1` to stop).
To avoid polling, you can use a fifo instead.